# Problem with IsKeyPressed 2 times

Tags: c++

i tried to make thing to show menu up by doing VK_MULTIPLY and close it by doing VK_MULTIPLY, but this does not work..
Anyone can help :) ?

```
        if (IsKeyPressed(VK_MULTIPLY))
        {
            Menu::MenuLevelHandler::MoveMenu(SubMenus::NOMENU);
        }
        else if (IsKeyPressed(VK_MULTIPLY)) //????
        {
            Menu::MenuLevelHandler::BackMenu();
        }
```

Comment: What framework are you using?

Comment: Voting to close because we don't have a clue about the API you're using. Also, why doesn't it work? What do you get? Obviously, having the same check for both the if and the else if will result in the else if never visited, so what is the issue you're having?

Comment: VK_MULTIPLY is triggered when a key is pressed, released OR typed.  That means you are triggering on key down AND key up.  That will cause it to be triggered twice - on key down and on key up.

Comment: Im using base called nano. While i try close and open from same key, it just flashes, it doesn't close.

Comment: Are you trying to make a mod for GTA5 or something? https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/2225755-post373.html

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

I think the `IsKeyPressed` check is checking if the key is pressed continuously.
Therefor both conditions are met.

Look for a `IsKeyDown` or `IsKeyUp` implementation. This should met your requirements.

Comment: i get error when i try add IsKeyDown or IsKeyUp